# awk strings and put it in the same line

Tags: shell, awk

can someone help me to format the file below (file_origin) with awk program to the file result below (file_result), thanks.

file_origin:

> 2017-11-11 09:01:12,m02occ3,transactions.tps,692
>
> 2017-11-11 09:01:12,m04occ1,transactions.tps,710
>
> 2017-11-11 09:01:12,m07occ4,transactions.tps,688
>
> 2017-11-11 09:01:12,m10occ2,transactions.tps,714
>
> 2017-11-11 09:06:12,m02occ3,transactions.tps,704
>
> 2017-11-11 09:06:12,m04occ1,transactions.tps,714
>
> 2017-11-11 09:06:12,m07occ4,transactions.tps,702
>
> 2017-11-11 09:06:12,m10occ2,transactions.tps,732
>
> 2017-11-11 09:11:12,m02occ3,transactions.tps,708
>
> 2017-11-11 09:11:12,m04occ1,transactions.tps,729
>
> 2017-11-11 09:11:12,m07occ4,transactions.tps,705
>
> 2017-11-11 09:11:12,m10occ2,transactions.tps,726
>
> 2017-11-11 09:16:12,m02occ3,transactions.tps,716
>
> 2017-11-11 09:16:12,m04occ1,transactions.tps,733
>
> 2017-11-11 09:16:12,m07occ4,transactions.tps,716
>
> 2017-11-11 09:16:12,m10occ2,transactions.tps,734
>
> 2017-11-11 09:21:12,m02occ3,transactions.tps,719
>
> 2017-11-11 09:21:12,m04occ1,transactions.tps,745
>
> 2017-11-11 09:21:12,m07occ4,transactions.tps,724
>
> 2017-11-11 09:21:12,m10occ2,transactions.tps,745

file_result:

> 2017-11-11 09:01:12,m02occ3,m04occ1,m07occ4,m10occ2,692,710,688,714
>
> 2017-11-11 09:06:12,m02occ3,m04occ1,m07occ4,m10occ2,704,714,702,732
>
> 2017-11-11 09:11:12,m02occ3,m04occ1,m07occ4,m10occ2,708,729,705,726
>
> 2017-11-11 09:16:12,m02occ3,m04occ1,m07occ4,m10occ2,716,733,716,734
>
> 2017-11-11 09:21:12,m02occ3,m04occ1,m07occ4,m10occ2,719,745,724,745

Comment: its better to explain what you want to do and provide an example of what you have done so far

Comment: i want to format the file_origin to file_result (as showed above with awk program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but it can be done as follows:

assumptions (according to your provided data and example)

1. each 4 lines will result in a single line and having same date value
2. the second column order is repeated always like: m02occ3, m04occ1, m07occ4, m10occ2

note: the getline function will read the next line

code:

```
awk '{
    v_date=$1;
    v1=$4;
    getline;
    v2=$4;
    getline;
    v3=$4;
    getline;
    v4=$4;
    print v_date ",m02occ3,m04occ1,m07occ4,m10occ2," v1 "," v2 "," v3 "," v4;
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '{if($1 in a) {a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2; b[$1]=b[$1] FS $NF} 
            else        {a[$1]=$2;          b[$1]=$NF}} 
       END {for(k in a) print k FS a[k] FS b[k]}'
```

construct two lists by concatenating second fields and last fields for each key field (first field).  Once done, print them by key.  Concatenation requires the first field treated differently (we want one less field separator than the number of fields concatenated), that's why there is a check whether that particular key was observed before `($1 in a)`

As a learning experience you can remove  `else` block and `if()` condition, just use the if statement instead and observe the effect.

Comment: it works perfectly also, thanks a lot for your support